Is 混 ever used as shorthand for 混沌?
I am working on a wiki for a Chinese web novel, and the author uses the term 混洞. I don't have a lot of context, because 混 is repeatedly used as a descriptor. For example, here's a sentence - 这幽暗混洞才感觉到有些‘撑’
People have been using machine translations, etc. and translating it as Chaos Hole, but I'm not quite confident that's the actual translation. Was hoping for some help here; for additional context, the author does use '混沌' repeatedly, which is another reason that I don't think he means chaos hole when he says 混洞. Thanks!

No, 混沌 is a specific noun that cannot be shortened in any form

If you post a paragraph or 2 of this wiki text, or a link to it, I think it would be easier to give an answer. Wiki is really not very reliable!

Thanks, I was thinking it shouldn't be shortened! Sorry, so I'm working on the wiki, but it's for a web novel...I'll paste a bit below (this is from Swallowed Star 2)
罗峰一念起，顿时体内开辟出一幽暗混洞，在开辟世界方面，罗峰经验已经非常丰富了。以‘混天分支’为根基，开辟更是简单。
大量能量涌入幽暗混洞内，形成一缕缕刀光，这无数刀光蕴含生命之源、生命灵性，不断汇聚凝练。
仅仅片刻，便是难以计数的刀光涌入其中，罗峰在无限空间的这一具身体的能量储备都消耗了三分之一，这幽暗混洞才感觉到有些‘撑’。
“成了。”
罗峰感应到，此刻在幽暗混洞内孕育出了一道无比凝练的‘刀光’。这一道刀光，罗峰仅仅看到都有些心惊肉跳。
无尽锋芒！

I prefer 混=不分，to not differ. 混洞=朦胧，hazy. Note that 混 usually denotes the concept of to mix something in daily usage.
Here is the most relevant literature I can find. Excerpt from 中國道教大辭典 p1056,

混洞太無元
指天地未生前的一種狀態。《洞玄靈寳自然九天生神章經解義》：混洞太無元者，混以不分為義，洞以虛通為義，太以極大為義，無以真空爲義。此明大道之本體，渾淪洞徹先天地生，而實無形體之可即，故曰混沌太無也。

where 混 denotes the meaning of 不分 / not differing, 洞 denotes the meaning of 虚通 / vaguely connecting. It is an unofficial translation since I can't find the English version of this book.

这幽暗混洞才感觉到有些‘撑’

IMO you can translate 混洞 into hazy as an adj. parallel with 幽暗, since 洞 contains the meaning of vague / hazy and 混 of confusing / ambiguous.
